# Building an embeddable (minimal) Python distribution on Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, software-distribution

Version 3.5.0 of Python introduced the [embeddable distribution](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution); a minimal Python distribution for Windows, meant to be bundled with other software that make use of Python in one way or another, e.g. via [embedding](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html). This enables precise control of what version of Python is used by the application that embeds it (which is vital in my case).

How can this be achieved in Linux? My guess is that I could just build Python from source, using `make altinstall` in order to build a standalone distribution to a specific directory, and then just bundle that directory with my application upon release. But is there a better way, e.g. a specific compilaton flag, to specifically to build a *minimal* distribution, i.e. the counterpart to the embeddable distribution for Windows?

Comment: I do have the exact same question for MacOs. I need to distribute an app and don't want the user to have to install python. And I also need control over the version.